# Getting the value from List

Tags: python

I am trying to utilize nova CLI tool for getting the server names from devstack setup.

Hence this is the code which leads me to get the result as needed.

```
# Establish the connection Keystone
nova = client.Client('2', 'admin', 'password', 'admin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0')

server_list = nova.servers.list(search_opts={'all_tenants':1,'tenant_id':'b0116ce25cad4106becbbddfffa61a1c'})
print server_list
```

This server list returning the data as follows:

```
[<Server: demo_ins1>]
```

Type is as follows:

```
<type 'list'>
```

Now my question is to now I can be able to get the server name here , that is "demo_ins1" from the list.

Some one let me know the way for the same.

Note: This is the default value returned by the novacliclient itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the same.

Basically, It was a class object inside the list.

I can be able to find that it was a class object when I was trying to execute the following code.

```
 for server_list in server_list:
        print server_list
        print type(server_list)
        print server_list.name
```

Hence I applied the server_list.name for getting the name as needed.

So now it is fine for the same.